# Как лучше строить базу даных дерева категорий?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, data-structures

есть категории и под категории как будет лучше и правильнее сделать через две или три таблицы?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если хотите сделать бесконечное tree меню, то id,name,parent и все это через рекурсию

Comment: Выкиньте `subcatecories` и в первом и во втором случае. в первом в `categories` добавьте `parent_id` со ссылкой на `id`. Во втором `subcategories_id` пусть ссылается тоже на `id` из `categories_copy1`. Да. В SQL это нормально ссылаться из таблицы  на саму себя. Так на фига Вам лишние таблицы `subcategiries`? А если у `subcategories` будут `subsubcategories`, Вы так и будите добавлять таблицы `subsubsubsub...subcategories`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один вариант, когда под-категория может содержаться только в одной категории

```
+------------+  
| categories |  
+------------+  
| id         |<---.  
| parent_id  |>>--'  
| name       |
+------------+
```

Другой, универсальный, вариант, когда под-категории могут быть в разных категориях

```
+------------+      +-------------------------+  
| categories |      | category_subcategories  |
+------------+      +-------------------------+
| id         |<---<<| category_id             |
| name       |  `-<<| subcategory_id          |
+------------+      +-------------------------+
```

Устанавливая определённые ограничения (уникальный ключ по subcategory_id в category_subcategories) можно добиться что бы второй вариант работал как первый: каждая под-категория только в категории.

От Ваших отличается отсутствием таблиц под-категорий. Под-категории тоже являются категориями, так зачем усугублять лишними таблицами? Меньше таблиц - крепче сон.
Глубина ничем не ограничена. Хотите - сидите со своими двумя, хотите - растите вглубь.

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от того, нужна ли возможность включать одну и ту же подкатегорию в две или более других категорий. Если такая возможность нужна вам придется использовать три таблицы.

Если каждая категория может иметь только одного родителя, то лучше воспользоваться первым вариантом с двумя таблицами. Когда объем категоризируемых данных достигнет пары гигабайт - с первым вариантом вам будет проще - он более удобен для оптимизации, так как в большинстве запросов можно обойтись без IN и индексов в покрывающем режиме.